# Mysql do not release memory

Tags: php, mysql, linux, cron

I have a project that uses 5 different data bases(oracle, mssql, ibm Informix , etc, ... and ...mysql)

Every timeout cron imports data into MySQL. Unfortunatelly we have one very huge cron script, that imports nearly 400 k rows. I made it to import data by small packs, but still, when cron runs this script, MySQL takes nearly 2 GB og memory, and wait for next call. Than takes 2 GB more, and this repeats before MySQL crashes.

We have already faced to the problem that MySQL innodb was corrupted and ran recovery mode from 1 to 4 to restart data base several times.

Total server virt memory is 12 GB.

Our configuration of /etc/my.cnf.d/ server.cnf looks like this:

```
    #
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
#
# See the examples of server my.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql/
#

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]
default_storage_engine=innodb
character-set-server=utf8

back_log = 50
max_connections = 100
max_connect_errors = 10
table_open_cache = 2048

max_allowed_packet = 64M
binlog_cache_size = 16M
max_heap_table_size = 1G


read_buffer_size = 8M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
sort_buffer_size = 8M
join_buffer_size = 8M

thread_cache_size = 32
# You should try [number of CPUs]*(2..4) for thread_concurrency
thread_concurrency = 8

query_cache_size = 64M
query_cache_limit = 1M

tmp_table_size = 1G

thread_stack = 240K

transaction_isolation = REPEATABLE-READ
ft_min_word_len = 4

log-bin=mysql-bin
binlog_format=mixed

#slow_query_log
#long_query_time = 10
group_concat_max_len = 10000


#*** MyISAM Specific options
key_buffer_size = 16M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 64M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 10G
myisam_repair_threads = 1
myisam_recover

# *** INNODB Specific options ***
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend

innodb_write_io_threads = 8
innodb_read_io_threads = 8

innodb_thread_concurrency = 16

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1

innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
innodb_log_files_in_group = 3

innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90

innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120

expire_logs_days=5

[mysqldump]
# Do not buffer the whole result set in memory before writing it to
# file. Required for dumping very large tables
quick

max_allowed_packet = 256M


[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

# Only allow UPDATEs and DELETEs that use keys.
safe-updates

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 512M
sort_buffer_size = 512M
read_buffer = 8M
write_buffer = 8M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqld_safe]
# Increase the amount of open files allowed per process. Warning: Make
# sure you have set the global system limit high enough! The high value
# is required for a large number of opened tables
open-files-limit = 8192
```

If any info is necessary to find out why this happens  I will provide it.

Please! help me to find out the solution ! Should I reinstall MySQL, or it is still possible to resolve by config modifications???

Comment: It sounds like you're throwing at MySQL more than it can take.
If you have stronger DBs in your project, why not use one of them for this import job? (I know Oracle can tackle something like this easily)

Comment: Google: MySQL Load data local infile.

Comment: This is what happens when you try to insert 400,000 rows. Oh, btw. How much space does each row take up?

Comment: we have kohana project (on php) that is already written using mysql. Locally, on our server we have only Mysql,  other db's are remote. For other types of db we use leap connector and only imports real time data for statistics. we have no extra resources to set-up mssql or oracle here. We have enough memory to store... but why memory encreases so fast while importing... I made it to write dat by small portions

Comment: Also when having issues with bugs in MySQL: Look at MariaDB as alternative. They are way more active in fixing the issues with MySQL.

Comment: We have exactly MariaDB

Comment: I want to add. We have set up imports from all 5 db's by the one logic, and those  imports takes about 50-100 k rows at a time. But import logick cuts all data into pieces of 1k for import, and all worked very fine till now. But one of our developers, very brave  man =((((, ran out of memory while testing his bash imports, and crashed db first time ever. To start it he has deleted tmp dir of mysql and than had to enable  recovery mode 3 to make all start. Now we are facing with this issue of overloading virt memory for 3 days. Mysql crashes and so on...

Comment: Based on the information you provide, it is running out of memory. So tune the my.cnf file and reduce your allocations for any option which is using more than 1GB of memory. Dial it right back to see if it becomes stable and then increase options slowly until you find what your server can handle.

Comment: The memory usage is growing linearly. The max buffer size is 8 gb, so when bd reaches that amount, it falls. The virtual machine itself is working on...

Comment: This is not a fault of mysql. It has a tool for easily loading 400k of data which is LOAD DATA IN FILE